# Proof for: the norm of the product between two vectors is equal to the product of their norms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

I need to prove the following 
$\lVert \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\rVert_2 = \lVert \pmb{a}\rVert_2\cdot\lVert \pmb{b}\rVert_2$ where 
$\pmb{a}$ and $\pmb{b}$ are vectors and $\pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T$ is a matrix. This is one of the properties for vector norms.

All help is really appreciated. I have a suspicion that the following equations might be helpful in the derivations, considering they were given alongside the question:

$\lVert A\rVert_2 = \sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}$ where $\rho(A)$ is the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $A$.

Comment: What is $\rho$ in your definition of $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What has your question to do with `numerical-linear-algebra`? Or with `proof-theory`, which is a branch of Logic?

Comment: $\rho$ is the spectral radius.

Comment: Reply to Jose. This is my first question, so i might have misunderstood the scope of certain tags. :O

Comment: observe that $\lVert \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\rVert_M^2 = sup_{\pmb{x}\neq 0}\frac{\lVert \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\pmb{x}\rVert^2}{\lVert \pmb{x}\rVert^2} \geq \left. \frac{\lVert \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\pmb{x}\rVert^2}{\lVert \pmb{x}\rVert^2} \right|_{\pmb{x}=\pmb{b}} = \frac{\pmb{b}^T \pmb{b} \pmb{a}^T \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\pmb{b}}{\lVert \pmb{b}\rVert^2} = \lVert \pmb{a} \rVert^2\frac{\lVert \pmb{b} \rVert^4}{\lVert \pmb{b} \rVert^2} = \lVert \pmb{a} \rVert^2\lVert \pmb{b} \rVert^2$ for the lower bound

Comment: What if $a$ and $b$ are orthogonal unit vectors?  In my experience - perhaps limited - the property you mentioned isn't familiar to me as a property of a norm, and the usual definition of the $2$-norm does not have an additional $\rho$. To help those of us with a different background, could you please add some additional context to the question, such as the exact source of the problem and the definition of "vector norm" that you are using?

Comment: The definition of norm is the following: Let V be a vector space over K. We say that the map $||\dot||$ from V into R is a norm on V if the following axioms are satisfied: 1) ||v|| is larger or equal to 0 for all vectors in V. 2) ||av|| = |a|||V|| for all a in K and v in V. 3) ||v+ w|| <= ||v|| + ||w||. The small two denotes that we are talking about eucledian norm.

Comment: @George Hansen: thanks. In that definition, there is no requirement about what happens when you take the dot product of two vectors. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the $2$-norm, the coordinate vectors $i$ and $j$ have norm $1$ and their dot product is zero (the dot product is not a vector, but if it was it would have norm 0).

Comment: I think that in this question $\pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T$ is a matrix, using the term dot product is a bit misleading.

Comment: @P.Quinton: I agree - I spent a while trying to figure out the "error" in your answer, compared to the obvious counterexamples, and I think the only issue is that $ab^T$ is not the dot product.

Comment: Thank you to everyone who took time to help me! I really appreciate it :) In the future I will make sure to add additional information.

Comment: Is the problem solved ? you may want to mark it as such.

Comment: Im currently writing my own version of the proof (with my own explanations). Ill mark the problem as solved when im done :)

Comment: Is it correct that the reason you do not have to take square roots of ||a|| ||b|| is that they are constants, and constants can be taken out of norms?

Comment: Well $(\pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T) \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T = \lVert \pmb{a} \rVert^2 \cdot\lVert \pmb{b} \rVert^2 (\pmb{n}_{\pmb{a}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T)^T (\pmb{n}_{\pmb{a}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T)$ and if you take the eigen values of Matrix $a A$, you get $a$ times the eigenvalues of $A$, after the square root you get the wanted result.

Comment: by the way if there are further things you want to discuss with regards to my solution, you may want to comment on it directly, otherwise I won't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every where I use the $2$-norm

Observe that we can write 
$$
\pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T = \lVert \pmb{a} \rVert \cdot \lVert \pmb{b} \rVert \cdot\pmb{n}_{\pmb{a}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T
$$

Where $\pmb{n}_{\pmb{u}} = \frac{1}{\lVert \pmb{u} \rVert} \pmb{u}$ is the normalization of $\pmb{u}$. Now we have
\begin{align*}
(\pmb{n}_{\pmb{a}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T)^T (\pmb{n}_{\pmb{a}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T)&= \pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{a}}^T \pmb{n}_{\pmb{a}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T\\
&=\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T
\end{align*}
So that
\begin{align*}
\lVert \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\rVert &= \lVert \pmb{a} \rVert \cdot \lVert \pmb{b} \rVert \cdot \sqrt{\rho(\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T)}
\end{align*}

so we need to find the largest eigenvalue of $\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T$ but observe that it is a projection matrix :

$$(\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T)^2=\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T \pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T = \pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T$$

if we write $\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T = D\Sigma D^T$ the eigen decomposition, then we have $D\Sigma D^T = D\Sigma D^T D \Sigma D^T = D\Sigma^2 D^T$ which means by uniqueness of the eigen decomposition that $\Sigma^2=\Sigma$. Since it is a diagonal matrix we have that every eigen values satisfies $\sigma^2=\sigma$ so that they take value in $\lbrace 0 , 1 \rbrace$.

Now it only remains to show that there is a eigen value that is $1$. But $\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}$ is an eigenvector associated to eigenvalue $1$, indeed
$$(\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T)\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}} = \pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}$$

and so $\rho(\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}\pmb{n}_{\pmb{b}}^T) = 1$ which in turn means that
$$\lVert \pmb{a}\pmb{b}^T\rVert = \lVert \pmb{a} \rVert \cdot \lVert \pmb{b} \rVert $$